# how to change the texture of my plane?it has still the old texture

Tags: shaders

I duplicated a plane that has a marble texture on.
I made a new texture n then in shading tab brought a brick texture map n also normal map,but the texture is still marble.thought it could be a bug,I did it again n again 5 times n still no changes.how to give the brick bump to the plane?[image]

Comment: Please add additional screenshots of your material properties. My guess is that you have multiple materials on one object. I notice this because you are in Slot 2.
Possible solution would be to delete Slot 1 which i guess is your original material.

Comment: you were right.I removed slot 1.thanks for solution.